# unable to access my site after nameserver change

Tags: dns, browser, nameserver

A few days ago, I purchased a domain on godaddy and set its nameservers to netlify's nameservers as a temporary change. The site and domain worked fine and I viewed it on chrome on my phone and PC.

Later I created a digitalocean droplet, configured it and then set the nameservers of the existing domain to digitalocean's nameservers. I have checked the site via its IP Address and it is working. I waited for a day for the DNS change to propagate and now I find that the domain doesn't resolve to the site for the browsers where I previously visited that address, but works fine on other browsers.

I have check hosts file, used `ipconfig /flushdns` and cleared dns cache and flushed s

Comment: Did you actually add DNS records via DigitalOcean's control panel (or copy the ones you had at Netlify)? Do they resolve via command line?

Comment: What  is the domain name?

Comment: @grawity you mean the a and cname records

Comment: @davidgo the domain name is bitoverflow.in

Comment: What browsers were you using to test the site? If it was Chrome,Chrome caches DNS Requests itself. Please visit chrome://net-internals/#dns in chrome and click "clear host cache".

Comment: @CraftyB I have cleared host cache and flushed sockets as well